# How do you use the Google+ SIgn In button to get a oauth token?

Tags: android, oauth, google-plus

I'm trying to use the G+ SignInButton to get a oauth token for sending to a web service to authenticate with that service. I'm having a lot of problems getting through the Google documentation on this, as it seems to be trying to do a lot more than simple authentication, and their section on oauth seems to be specific to using it to access Google services, which isn't what I'm doing.

Implementing the Facebook login button was fairly simple, install the library, implement the button, the callback gives you a token. Is there some G+ equivalent I'm just not finding? This is all feeling ridiculously complicated for such a simple task, in addition to the fact that I can't get it working.

Comment: Have you looked at the new [Google Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) docs?